# Creation of hpp file in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, header

When I'm about to add a new file to a project with Visual Studio and I want it to be `.hpp`, only `.h` files are available.

How to create `.hpp` files?

Comment: `.h` header are c-style header files, that endured till c++. It is good practice to use `hpp` as c++ header files, and visual studio uses `<iostream>` instead of `"iostream.h"` since a while. So you can feel free to name your header files with a hpp ending, but should not wonder if you find libarries with .h around in c++ yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the extension to whatever you want when you add a new file.
Just change the name from "Header.h" or whatever default it gives you to your chosen name.

[image: For exmaple]

Comment: Can Visual Studio be configured to use `.hpp` directly instead of renaming every file?

Comment: I don't think so, but things may have changed

Answer (score 1):

`.h` is a perfectly valid alternative for `.hpp`. It's just an extension for a header, it doesn't mean it's [c](/questions/tagged/c).

Your compiler will treat this file the same way no matter whether the extension is `.h` or `.hpp`. Yet if for some reason you still need `.hpp` extension, just click ***New Item*** ~> ***Header File (.h)*** and at the bottom name it with `.hpp` extension.

Alternatively you might create `.h` and just rename it directly within the solution explorer.