# How to change the default new item extension from .h to .hpp in Visual Studio (2013)

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying to change the default new item extension from "*.h*" to "*.hpp*".

[*The picture of this post*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112553/creation-of-hpp-file-in-visual-studio) shows what I mean.
I already got it functionally working with [*this approach*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e2b4aa7c-73c7-426b-9825-f5db01a9870d/hpp-header-files), by changing:

- the *..\VC\vcprojectitems\hfile.h* filename to *hfile.hpp*,
- "*HFile.h...*" to "*HFile.hpp...*" in the *..\VC\vcprojectitems\VCProjectItems.vsdir* file
- "*..\HFile.h...*" to "*..\HFile.hpp...*" in the *..\VC\vcprojectitems\Code\code.vsdir* file
- "*..\VCProjectItems\HFile.h...*" to "*..\VCProjectItems\HFile.hpp...*" in the *..VC\VCNewItems\NewItems.vsdir* file

What is now left is the description. You can see it on the picture and it should be "*Header File(.hpp)*" instead of "*Header File(.h)*" How/Where do I change this?

I know it is such a little thing and it doesn't affect the functionality, but I want it nevertheless. Also is my approach a good one with changing those files or is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: The string is *localized*.  The #1080 you see in the .vsdir file is the resource ID of the string.  They are stored in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcpackages\1033\vcpkgui.dll on an English version of VS, replace 1033 by your LCID.  You can edit them with VS, I do not recommend that.  One thing to try is to replace "#1080" with the string you want.  Might work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Almost the correct answer: I checked the vcpkgui.dll -> String Table for the correct resource ID. #1080 seems to be the default name ("Header.hpp" in my case) and #1078 was the one I was looking for. So I just had to replace |#1078| (before the |15|) with |Header File (.hpp)|, like Hans Passantsuggested, in each of the 3 files and now everything works like intendend!

Comment: Hmya, I you ignored my warning.  It is very important that you restore the file with its original time-stamp before you install a Visual Studio Update.  Installers tend to skip modified files, that's Very Bad for a DLL like this one.

Comment: Oh no, I didn't touch the dll file, just took a peek into it to find the correct resourceID and I copied it before and just checked the copy, so this should be fine? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay.  These resource IDs don't seem the match well with my version of vcpkgui.dll.  Odd.  I've got #1078 = "Header File (.h)", #1079 = "Creates a C++ header file", #1080 = "Header".  My comment was indeed wrong, it is #1078, #1080 appears to be the file's default name.  How you got ".hpp" out of changing the resource ID is very unclear to me.

Comment: I've got the same id's like you listed above :) And I got .hpp because of the changes I made shown in the question, the default file name is still only "Header", like it is for you, sry if I mixed something there... It just says "Header.hpp" now if I click on the Header File label instead of "Header.h".

Comment: I posted pretty pictures of doing this for VS2017 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413254/how-do-you-make-hpp-extension-default-in-vs-2017/57920331#57920331) to a similar question.