# How to set default header file extension in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Every time I create headers I have to manually rename their extensions from `.h` to `.hpp`.

And when I create C++ Projects with wizards, header files get created with the .h extension.

Is there any way to change C++ Headers' default file extension in Visual Studio 2013?

I know, it's a matter of personal preference, but I want to do it anyway.

Comment: VS2013 does not support custom project item templates yet.  Maybe next version.  You can tinker with the files in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcprojectitems directory but it is risky.  Be sure to make a good backup.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083802/how-to-change-the-default-new-item-extension-from-h-to-hpp-in-visual-studio-2

Comment: Why _would_ it affect performance? lulz. Besides, there are many many other factors to consider for "doing things" that do not involve performance. Anyway, I acknowledge that this is just your personal choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio world uses ".h" extension, that's just the way it is and it makes no difference whatsoever the extension you use. They all become part of your ".cpp" files anyway when the are "included", they are literally copied in in-place of the "#include" line when the compiler runs. They can have any extension at all. It also doesn't matter if the source files are ".c" or ".cpp", the compile mode is set in the project properties, and will be C++ unless you deliberately change it, which would render most of the SDK unusable anyway.

Comment: Well but when I want to compile those header files standalone e.g. with clang++ it gives a warning that compiling .h files as c++ code is deprecated. You actually didn't answer the question.