# How do you make .hpp extension default in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way that i can make the .hpp extension default instead of .h in VS 2017?

Currently, when adding a new file it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUzuZ.jpg).

Its not that its a huge issue, but having to write .hpp very single time manually its just inconvienent.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>This information comes from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083802/how-to-change-the-default-new-item-extension-from-h-to-hpp-in-visual-studio-2) which is essentially the same, except that one is about VS2013. For VS2013 I think the first step should point to either *%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcprojectitems\* OR *%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\VC\vcprojectitems\*, but can't confirm.</sub>

1. Navigate to *%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\vcprojectitems\*.  This will likely bring you to *C:\Program Files (x86)\...*
2. Open *VCProjectItems.vsdir* in a text editor, such as Notepad++.

[image: Arrow pointing to VC Project Items file to be opened.]

3. Change *HFile.h* to *HFile.hpp* and on the same line change *#1078* to *Header File (.hpp)* and change *#1080* to *Header.hpp*. Save the file.

[image: Arrows pointing to text that needs changed in VC Project Items file.]

[image: Arrows pointing to text that's been changed in VC Project Items file.]

4. Back in the file explorer, rename *hfile.h* to *hfile.hpp*.

[image: Arrow pointing to h file file to be renamed.]

5. Now you get the intended functionality in the *Visual C++* menu.

[image: Arrows point to functioning filename and description in Visual C++ heading of Add New Item menu.]

6. Open the *Code* subfolder.

[image: Arrow pointing to Code folder to be opened.]

7. Open *code.vsdir* with a text editor.

[image: Arrow pointing to code file to be opened.]

8. Repeat the changes to the last *.vsdir* file: Change *HFile.h* to *HFile.hpp* and on the same line change *#1078* to *Header File (.hpp)* and change *#1080* to *Header.hpp*. Save the file.

[image: Arrows point to text that needs changed in code file.]

[image: Arrows pointing to text that's been changed in code file.]

9. Now you get the intended functionality in the *Code* menu.

[image: Arrows point to functioning filename and description in Code heading of Add New Item menu.]

**I have no idea what the next steps actually change, but it looks like it ought to change *something*.**

10. Navigate back up one folder to *vcprojectitems*, then another folder to *VC*. Open the *VCNewItems* folder.

[image: Arrow pointing to "folder up" button to vc project items.]

[image: Arrow pointing to "folder up" button to vc.]

[image: Arrow pointing to VC New Items folder to be opened.]

11. Open *NewItems.vsdir* with a text editor.

[image: Arrow pointing to New Items file to be opened.]

12. Repeat the changes to the last two *.vsdir* files: Change *HFile.h* to *HFile.hpp* and on the same line change *#1078* to *Header File (.hpp)* and change *#1080* to *Header.hpp*. Save the file.

[image: Arrows point to text that needs changed in New Items file.]

[image: Arrows pointing to text that's been changed in New Items file.]